# Passing Int arguments to mutations relay and typescript

Tags: typescript, graphql, relay, relaymodern

I am using a schema first approach have the following Input type for a mutation

```
input VerifyBankAccountInput {
  bankAccountId: ID!
  amount1Cents: Int!
  amount2Cents: Int!
}
```

On the frontend I am using relay with typescript. In the generated `graphql.ts` file the `Int` type gets mapped to `number`. I make sure these two amounts are `number` (and not `string`) before I pass it to the mutation. However, in the POST query from graphql I notice that these values become `Float` and my server errors because of that. It's not really consistent across dev and prod or across the two values either as shown below (both use exact same code).

`input:{bankAccountId: "SomeRelayId", amount1Cents: 56.99999999999999, amount2Cents: 61}`

How do I make sure that the `number` is sent as an `Int` and not a `Float` in a mutation?

I tried following the suggestions here https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/11/05/using-an-int-type-in-typescript/ but got stuck because the generated code in `graphql.ts` still expects a `number`. Getting error: `Type 'BigInt' is not assignable to type 'number'.`

I could go and change the type in the generated `graphql.ts` but that would be overwritten every time I recompile using `"relay-compiler --src ./src --schema ./schema.graphql --language typescript --customScalars.URL=URL --customScalars.LocalDate=LocalDate --customScalars.Instant=string"` .

I could also simply round the `number` to make sure there are no decimal places but that seems a bit brittle to me.

What is the right way to handle this with the schema first approach?